# How can I create a checkable menu item from a bound observable collection of models in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to populate the contents of a menuItem's items from a bound observable collection (populated in my viewmodel) of a model; CheckableItemModel which simply contains a string, 'DisplayName' and a bool for 'IsChecked', which I want to bind to the Header and IsChecked properties of a MenuItem respectively. For context, this model is:

```
public class CheckableItemModel
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => isChecked;
        set
        {
            bool updated = isChecked != value;
            isChecked = value;
            if (updated)
                CheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, isChecked);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<bool> CheckedChanged;
}
```

I can bind to these properties just fine in many cases and it functions, the issue is the UI. I have a custom menuItem style defined in my App.xaml, which targets Menu and MenuItem, so they automatically display as the custom style. Through research, the best approach seems to be a heirarchicalDataTemplate. This is my current solution, however the issue is, is that I can't make the menuItem itself checkable, so far all I have been able to do is add a checkbox and bind that to my model properties, however it doesn't look the same as a checkable menu item and I'd like the UI of this application to look consistent. My current code for this version is here:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="TypesMenuItem"
          Header="Types"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntryTypes}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntryTypes}">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}">
            </CheckBox>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Another solution I have tried is a new ItemTemplate, which works in that the item is checkable and binds properly, however this re-targets the base menu item, so I lose my custom menu style. And it just looks like the default menu item. I could copy my entire style from app.xaml, but this seems unnecessary.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MessagesMenuItem"
      IsEnabled="{Binding HasProcessedDataForSelectedFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      Header="Messages" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding LogTopics, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsCheckable"  Value="{Binding IsCheckable}" />
            <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick"  Value="{Binding IsCheckable}" />
            <Setter Property="IsChecked"  Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Is there any solution here that would allow the menu item to be inherently checkable, bind to my model properties, and use the style I have defined in App.xaml? My last idea is a converter from my binding to the model collection, which seems a bit smelly to me, and won't bind (I think).

Comment: Seems you just need to combine the style in App.xaml that likely pimps up the look&feel of the menu item, with the inline style shown in your post, that targets functionality and databinding.

Maybe `<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem} BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleInAppXaml}"` is all you need?

Comment: BasedOn is kind of "inheritance" for styles in xaml...

Comment: Thanks @lidqy, I'd been hoping it would automatically pick up the style as my other menu items had (key in app.xaml was Key="{x:Type MenuItem}"). Just renamed this to something, and made every menu item explicitly use the style, which seems to have worked. Thanks!